# JavaScript, ajax Auto - Login

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, curl

What is wrong http://jsfiddle.net/qch1vtqc/

I'm trying to create an Automatic Log On another web page , without leaving the current page , beer somehow I have not succeeded.

```
<form id="loginForm" name="loginForm" method="post" 
      action="http://www.streamuj.tv/login">
  <p>
    <label for="name">Uživatel:</label>
    <br>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="examplename" size="22" 
           tabindex="3" id="name" class="logintext">
    <br>
    <label for="password">Heslo:</label>
    <br>
    <input name="password" type="password" value="exampepass" 
           class="logintext" id="password" tabindex="4" size="22">
    <br>
    <a href="http://www.streamuj.tv/recoverpassword" 
       title="Forgot!">Zapomněli jste heslo?</a><br>
    <input type="hidden" name="action_login" value="Přihlásit se">
    <input type="image" src="http://www.streamuj.tv/images/login.gif" 
           tabindex="5" class="loginbutton">
  </p>
</form>
```

Please you have any idea how to create an automatic login with pre-defined values ​​, but not without abandoning the current page? Thank you very much in advance for your help and sorry for my English .

Comment: http://www.9lessons.info/2014/07/ajax-php-login-page.html follow this .Hope it will serve your purpose.

Comment: Maybe https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Same-origin_policy?  Also, look into https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTTP/Access_control_CORS.

Comment: Any idea (sample) as implemented in reals please? I'm not a programmer, but only an amateur so that I'm trying to add to my already created pages ....